# SQL query to bring back list of servers from specific date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-formatting

I'm trying to make a query with **SQL Server Management Studio 2017** that brings back a count of all the servers with a projected migration date of this year. I have one query made now, but it's still bringing back some servers with dates from years before.

`SELECT MONTH(Projected) as [Month], count(*) as [Total]
FROM dbo.tFake
WHERE Projected >='01/01/2019' AND Projected <='12/31/2019
GROUP BY Month(Projected)
ORDER BY [Month]`

Date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` btw. How can I get this query to bring back just servers that are projected for the year 2019?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have an unclosed quotation mark, although I suspect that's a typo, since the code as written won't run.  Please post a data sample that returns servers outside your date range.  You could also try "Where Year(Projected) = 2019" rather than two date comparisons.

Comment: What do you mean the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`? Date & time data types don't have a format in SQL Server. You aren't storing dates storing dates as a `varchar` are you? a `varchar` is not a date, and this would explain why you're getting the wrong data; you've chosen the wrong data type. For example, with a `varchar` the statement `'12/01/2000' > '01/01/2019'` is **true**. Why? Because `varchar`'s are compared using their characters from left to right. As `'1' > '0'` this means that `'12/01/2000' > '01/01/2019'`.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the assumption that your data type is wrong, the first step is to fix that. 
**Note, I am assuming that your data only contains dates, and not time (which your query implies)**. Firstly, you'll need to change the value of all your rows to an convertible value, we'll go with the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`:

```
UPDATE dbo.tFake
SET Projected = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,Projected,101),112);
```

Now that all the rows are a literal string in the format `yyyyMMdd` we can alter the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tFake ALTER COLUMN Projected date;
```

Now, we can run your query again, but now your data type is correct, you won't have the problem:

```
SELECT MONTH(Projected) as [Month], count(*) as [Total]
FROM dbo.tFake
WHERE Projected >= '20190101' AND Project < '20200101' --I prefer the >= and < method. This is especially import with date & time data types
GROUP BY Month(Projected)
ORDER BY [Month];
```

Notice the literal strings I passed are also in the `yyyyMMdd` format. If you *must* pass a literal string in the format `MMddyyyy` you can wrap in a `CONVERT` with the style code `101`: `CONVERT(date,'12/31/2019',101)`. `101` means the US style date ([CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

*Remember, this solution **assumes** you have date only values, and not date and time values. If you do (have date and time values) you'll want to use an appropriate date and time data type and use the ISO8601 style, instead of the ISO style.*

Comment: This definitely helped! I was able to get the query bring back exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @ScaredIntern . Please do mark the answer as the solution if it did solve your problem, so that future readers know the answer helped. Thanks.